# Office365 API to get user's region and time zone setting

Tags: outlook, office365api

Is there a way to get user's region and time zone settings by Office365 API v2.0?

What I have done: Query for user's basic profile but did not find it.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me",
  "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('00064000-a768-901b-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')",
  "Id": "00064000-a768-901b-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "EmailAddress": "re***g@hotmail.com",
  "DisplayName": "Shaocong Ren",
  "Alias": "puid-00064000A768901B",
  "MailboxGuid": "00064000-a768-901b-0000-000000000000"
}
```

Comment: The timezone is in the MailBox setting (which unfortunately means you need OAuth access to the email scope): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetAllMailboxSettings